# What opensource CMS: generates clean xhtml, is skinable with css, and has a lightweight markup content editor?

Tags: language-agnostic, content-management-system

See title. By lightweight markup I mean something like markdown or wikitext.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, silverstripe http://www.silverstripe.com/ is thought to be a good option for people who care about web standards , as is modx http://modxcms.com/

For a lighter editor, check out textpattern.com which uses textile (like markdown). If you're on rails, http://webby.rubyforge.org/ might do the trick.

http://www.madebyfrog.com is a port of the ruby CMS radiant that aims to be fast, light, and minimal.

Comment: Just curious, when you saw this question did it have any answers? or was it listed as unanswered. 2 people answered poorly before you and I asked them to delete their attempts because activity died. I might use this thread to support an issue on uservoice.

Comment: Yes, it was unanswered. It seems there is little to be gained by answering questions that have already been discussed, no matter how good your answer, the person who asked seems to never 'accept' the answer.

Comment: Agreed. I suggested that there be an "unresolved tab" for questions with no accepted answer. To combat the "never accepting" problem I suggested that askers be forced to ping the question periodically. failing to ping drops the q from unresolved. Vote for it: the link follows.

Comment: Check it in comments here: 
http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/23180

Decided to support this similar issue since it had momentum already.

Comment: Webby is not a Rails program.  It is a set of Ruby programs that generates html files -- that can be hosted on any server that knows how to serve html.

Comment: Ah, you meant "If you're on Ruby...", try Webby.  a-ok.

Answer (score 2):

[WordPress](http://wordpress.org) keeps getting better and better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm loving [modx](http://modxcms.com).

Answer (score 0):

I am a user of Joomla. I think Joomla is in the top five CMS.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/). Simple, easy to use and flexible, and it has markdown filters integrated.

Answer (score 0):

[Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) asp.net c# cms

Answer (score 0):

[Plone](http://plone.org) meets all those requirements, although it would be unusual to use markdown. (The underlying Zope platform definitely supports markdown, but in the Plone user interface, it's more usual to use the Kupu editor)

Edit: Since I wrote that, things have changed. Plone still supports [Kupu](http://www.tinymce.com/), but these days you also have the option to use [tinymce](http://plone.org) as your markup editor.